# Dimension mismatch for applying indices from one df to another df

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have df1 whose index has `df1.index.shape` of  `(80,)`. I have an numpy array `df2` which has `df2.shape` of `(80,2)`. However, when I try to convert `df2` to dataframe, `df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2,index=df1.index)`, I get the following error message:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (80, 2), indices imply (80, 80)

How come I receive this error? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works nice:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                    'B':[4,5,6]}, index=['a','b','c'])

print (df1)
   A  B
a  1  4
b  2  5
c  3  6

print (df1.index.shape)
(3,)

df2 = df1.values
print (df2)
[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]

print (df2.shape)
(3, 2)

print (pd.DataFrame(df2,index=df1.index))
   0  1
a  1  4
b  2  5
c  3  6
```

But if change `index` to `columns`, it raise error:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df2,columns=df1.index))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 3), indices imply (3, 3)
```

It raise error if length of `index` is different:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],
                    'B':[3,4],
                    'C':[5,6]}, index=['a','b'])

print (df1)
   A  B  C
a  1  3  5
b  2  4  6

idx = pd.Index([5,6,7])
print (idx)
Int64Index([5, 6, 7], dtype='int64')

print (idx.shape)
(3,)

df2 = df1.values
print (df2)
[[1 3 5]
 [2 4 6]]

print (df2.shape)
(2, 3)

print (pd.DataFrame(df2,index=idx))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 2), indices imply (3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a sample data sets, because everything is working in this simple example:

```
In [15]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (5, 4)))

In [16]: df2 = np.random.rand(5, 2)

In [17]: df1
Out[17]:
     0    1    2    3
0  724  639  288  169
1   49  271   75  161
2  728  329   78   23
3  586  407  407  390
4  132  661  704  273

In [18]: df2
Out[18]:
array([[ 0.19690057,  0.64171029],
       [ 0.61680318,  0.64391293],
       [ 0.4638142 ,  0.99877559],
       [ 0.12193726,  0.76737424],
       [ 0.34726316,  0.68705751]])

In [19]: pd.DataFrame(df2,index=df1.index)
Out[19]:
          0         1
0  0.196901  0.641710
1  0.616803  0.643913
2  0.463814  0.998776
3  0.121937  0.767374
4  0.347263  0.687058
```